# Strict Patch<T> type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, reactive-programming, patch, inference

I've often come across the requirement to 'patch' an object T through Object.assign().

For example during change propagation you may manipulate a stateful object which other code still has a reference to (typical of reactive programming, like MobX or Vue).

Of course it's important to ensure it still has a valid shape T at the end, since code elsewhere relies on it, and this has the danger of creating serious runtime errors.

So far, this has been done by brain, but I wonder how to get the Typescript compiler to help. I speculate that it is possible to define a `Patch<T>` type and a `function applyPatch<T, P extends Patch<T>>(current: T, patch: P)` which guarantees that the Patch will overwrite properties as necessary to ensure that the resulting object is still a T, whatever kind of T you started with.

The example below [see typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ53Vm) shows how you SHOULDN'T derive a Patch, since in combination with Object.assign it freely generates objects which are no longer T, but the compiler THINKS is a T. This will create runtime errors. In the code below, I never cast any object, so this is just an (inevitable?) Typescript [soundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) issue.

Can anyone suggest a definition of `Patch<T>` and `applyPatch()` that would ensure compilation errors on these unsound patch attempts.

The compiler should force the patch to have the correct properties - being explicit to overwrite any properties that might need aligning.

```js
type DataLoader<Ok, Error = unknown> =
  // loading true or false, but has nothing yet
  | ({ loading: boolean } & {
      data?: never;
      errors?: never;
    })
  // retrieval failed - loading===false, has errors
  | {
      loading: false;
      data?: never;
      errors: Error[];
    }
  // retrieval succeeded - loading===false, has data
  | {
      loading: false;
      data: Ok;
      errors?: never;
    };

/** Let's enumerate the 4 strictly-allowed variants of DataLoader<Foo> */

interface Foo {
  foo: "bar";
}

const createInitialValue = (): DataLoader<Foo> => ({ loading: false });

const createLoadingValue = (): DataLoader<Foo> => ({ loading: true });

const createSuccessValue = (): DataLoader<Foo> => ({
  loading: false,
  data: {
    foo: "bar",
  },
});

const createFailureValue = (): DataLoader<Foo> => ({
  loading: false,
  errors: [new Error("Went wrong")],
});

/** Let's try to define a safe patch routine */

/** Bad example of patch definition (for demonstration) */
type Patch<T> = Partial<T>;

function applyPatch<T, P extends Patch<T>>(current: T, patch: P) {
  return Object.assign(current, patch);
}

/** Now let's demonstrate how bad it is */

// in these examples, `loading` was set to `true`, but data or errors were left in place
// the patch should have been forced to set the `data` and `errors` values to `undefined`  
// accepted because Object.assign is not smart enough and DataLoaderPatch<T> is too loose
const keptDataByMistake: DataLoader<Foo> = applyPatch(
  createSuccessValue(),
  {
    loading: true,
  }
);
const keptErrorsByMistake: DataLoader<Foo> = applyPatch(
  createFailureValue(),
  {
    loading: true,
  }
);

// here the loading value stayed as `true`, which is incompatible with data, errors
// the patch should have been forced to set the loading value to false 
// accepted because Object.assign is not smart enough and DataLoaderPatch<T> is too loose
const successButStillLoadingMistake: DataLoader<Foo> = applyPatch(
  createLoadingValue(),
  {
    data: { foo: "bar" },
  }
);
const failureButStillLoadingMistake: DataLoader<Foo> = applyPatch(
  createLoadingValue(),
  {
    errors: [new Error("Went wrong")],
  }
);

/** Here we print out 4 examples of DataLoader<Foo> which are type-invalid, but were freely
 * made without compiler errors using the above patching procedure
 */
for (const loader of [
  keptErrorsByMistake,
  keptDataByMistake,
  successButStillLoadingMistake,
  failureButStillLoadingMistake,
]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(loader));
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is even feasible to create because all it can do is provide autocomplete and checking for **static calls where you know the T to patch and the P to patch with**. So basically it's useless because `DataLoader<Foo>` is a union and when you use this in whatever project you are making, the Patch type won't be of much use because everything will be `DataLoader<Foo>` anyways. Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do here?

Comment: Hi, Kelly. We disagree here. If myLoader currently fulfils ANY one of the union, there is a well-defined type GUARANTEED to Object.assign it to another well-typed union member. True, Patch<T> of a badly-designed union may be `never` - Object.assign() can't delete properties. DataLoader ensures there IS a Patch<DataLoader<T>> (it fully-specifies all properties - previously-set ones must be assigned undefined). But I want the compiler to check my work, with Patch<DataLoader<T>> driven by DataLoader<T> rather than my brain. My non-ideal workaround below uses typing of instances as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an adequate workaround which might be the best answer, unless someone has a better idea.

Sadly it doesn't achieve the ideal of a `SafePatch<T>` type (a union type guaranteeing that Object.assign(someT, safePatch) is also a T). This would be great as it would facilitate auto-completion.

However, introducing explicit typing that tracks the merge taking place in `Object.assign()` is enough to achieve fairly meaningful compiler errors (assuming you know how patching can fail).

The explicit type is `type Merged<Target, Source> = Omit<Target, keyof Source> & Source;` then   `return Object.assign(orig, patch) as Merged<Orig, Patch>;` returns sufficient type information to know that you may have made an object that isn't a T.

Compare the unsafePatch (simple `Object.assign`) with the safePatch (typed `Object.assign`) shown below (which you can explore at [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGRbXm)).

[image: correct detection of a bad patch]

The error appears like this, which is just about traceable...

[image: Error indicating a bad patch]

The full demonstration is below.

```js
function unsafePatch<Orig, Patch>(orig: Orig, patch: Patch) {
  return Object.assign(orig, patch);
}

function safePatch<Orig, Patch>(orig: Orig, patch: Patch) {
  return Object.assign(orig, patch) as Merged<Orig, Patch>;
}

const loader: DataLoader<string> = createSuccessValue();

{
  // unsafe version
  const badlyPatched: DataLoader<string> = unsafePatch(loader, {
    loading: true,
  });
  const wellPatched: DataLoader<string> = unsafePatch(loader, {
    loading: true,
    data: undefined,
    errors: undefined,
  });
}

{
  // safe version
  const badlyPatched: DataLoader<string> = safePatch(loader, {
    loading: true,
  });
  const wellPatched: DataLoader<string> = safePatch(loader, {
    loading: true,
    data: undefined,
    errors: undefined,
  });
}

function createInitialValue() {
  return { loading: false } as const;
}

function createLoadingValue() {
  return { loading: false } as const;
}

function createSuccessValue() {
  return {
    loading: false,
    data: "bar",
  } as const;
}

function createFailureValue() {
  return {
    loading: false,
    errors: [new Error("Went wrong")],
  } as const;
}

type Merged<Target, Source> = Omit<Target, keyof Source> & Source;

type DataLoader<Ok, Error = unknown> =
  // loading true or false, but has nothing yet
  | ({ loading: boolean } & {
      data?: never;
      errors?: never;
    })
  // retrieval failed - loading===false, has errors
  | {
      loading: false;
      data?: never;
      errors: Error[];
    }
  // retrieval succeeded - loading===false, has data
  | {
      loading: false;
      data: Ok;
      errors?: never;
    };
```